# Powershell: скрипт для удаления бэкапов

Tags: windows, powershell

Есть необходимость написать скрипт на Powershell для очистки дискового пространства от ненужных папок-бэкапов. Есть основные папки с именами-доменами. Внутри лежат папки с именами датами. Внутри этих папок лежат файлы бэкапа. Логика очистки такая: основные папки-домены удаляются по дате изменения (если старее 30 дней, то удалить), внутренние папки с именами-датами удаляются по именам. Мной написан этот скрипт:

```
$Folder = "C:\Users\Domain\Desktop\Main" 
$DayPeriod = "-30"
$CurrentDay = Get-Date
$ChangeOfDays = $CurrentDay.AddDays($DayPeriod)
$Backups = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder

Set-Location $Folder

foreach ($Backup in $Backups) {
    if ($Backup.LastWriteTime -lt ($CurrentDay).AddDays($DayPeriod)) {
            Remove-Item $Backup -recurse
    }   
    else {
            $SurviveFoldersList = ChildItem -path $Backup | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Last 10 
            Remove-Item -path $Backup\* -recurse -force -exclude $SurviveFoldersList
    }
}
```

Этот скрипт как и необходимо удаляет ненужные папки-домены по дате изменения и внутренние папки-даты по названию, но в тех папках-датах, которые он и не удалил он рекурсивно удаляет всё содержимое. То есть, папка остаётся, но пустой без самих нужных файлов бэкапа. Как можно ограничить удаление только на папках-датах?

Comment: Может не писать свои костыли, а воспользоваться готовыми решениями? Ведь потом `n+1` фича снова потребует времени, дебага и сопровождения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полное редактирование ответа.
Так как работа `exclude` команды `remove-item` ведет себя не так как ожидалось, предлагаю поменять процесс удаления:

```
ChildItem -path $Backup -Directory | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -SkipLast 10 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Выбирая только те каталоги, которые подходят под удаление пропуская первые 10 `Select-Object -SkipLast 10`

Отдельный вызов `remove-item` из скрипта убрать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Переменная $SurviveFoldersList нужна для исключения из удаления 10 самых свежих по дате в названии папок вложенных в папки домены. Нужен ли там Foreach-Object? По крайней мере, от удаления вложенных бэкап-файлов он не спасает, так ещё и удаляются все сами папки-даты

Comment: Хм, поведение действиетльно не явное, сейчас отредактирую ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Такой процесс удаления работает корректно. В теории, если бы у RI можно было вписывать два exclude, то можно было бы попробовать реализовать как в моем варианте добавив вторым вариантом exclude переменную $SurviveFoldersList/*, как думаете?

Comment: Да, ваш вариант бы сработал, если бы исключение применялись корректно командлетом.